# zsh: segmentation fault in C after compile

Tags: c

I have an program in C for showing appropiate number prime (max or min). After input a value, i have error "zsh:segmentation fault". Why?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(int n){
    for (int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    if(n%i == 0)
    return max(n+1);
    return n;
}

int min(int n){
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    if(n%i==0)
    return min(n-1);
    return n;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Numarul =");scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Numarul anterior prim numarului dat este %d",min(n));
        printf("Numarul urmator prim numarului dat este %d",max(n));

}
```

Comment: In this case, it is probably a stack overflow.

Comment: `After input this` What do you input _exactly_? You run your program, then you type "this" and press enter?

Comment: You have endless recursions.

Comment: `i<=n` should be `i<n`. Because `n%n` will be 0, even for primes, and then you go for the `n+1`-branch.

Comment: Your `max()` never stops. `max(3)` ==> `3%2 == 1` ==> `3%3 == 0` ==> `max(4)` ==...==> `max(5)` ==> `max(infinity)`

Comment: Side remark: actually it's enough to go until the square root of n (but then it has to remain`<=`).

Comment: I did it, thank you so much.